# Sorting results of aggregate function

Tags: sql, function, aggregate, grouping

This code:

```
SELECT ProductID, COUNT(ProductID) AS Occurrences
FROM OrderDetails
Group By ProductID;
```

is my attempt to take the productIDs that occur in an orderDetails table, count how many orders contain that product, and then sort the productID counts descending. In layman's terms, I want to show which products are the most popular, by showing their count in descending order so that the products that "sold" the most will occur at the top. The issue I have is that when I tried to use "Group by" with "Occurrences", it spat out an error that I cannot use aggregate functions with group by. If I group by ProductID, it shows the counts all over the place, which isn't the most useful way to present the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* work:

```
SELECT ProductID, COUNT(ProductID) AS Occurrences
FROM OrderDetails
Group By ProductID
Order By COUNT(ProductID) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to use if you want to know the popularity of the products is `SUM` not `COUNT`:

```
SELECT ProductID,
       sum(Qty) AS Occurrences
FROM   OrderDetails
Group  By ProductID
Order  By sum(Qty) DESC;
```

`COUNT` will give you interesting results. Or you could use count of orders like this:

```
select ProductID
       count(distinct OrderNumber) as NumberOfOrders
from OrderDetails
group by ProductID
order by count(distinct OrderNumber) desc;
```

Comment: The only thing that confused me was the use of "Qty". I don't know if you were using it as a placeholder for something else or what, but in my code I would be using ProductID because I want to count(or sum) the number of times each product appears in the orderDetail table.

Comment: @TophHughes - I used "Qty" because I'm not sure what the column is called in your table but typically you would have a quantity ordered column in an "OrderDetails" table. Consider the case where product A is ordered 10 times and product B is ordered 5 times and one of the product B orders is for a quantity of 12. I would consider product B to be more popular.